# In werewolv.es, will a Djinn or a Succubus be killed if visiting the same target as an Omegawolf?

Tags: werewolv.es

According to the H2P for the Omegawolf:

> When the Omegawolf visits a target they will kill the target and ALL other visitors

However, for the purposes of Stalker, Harlot, Insomniac, etc. reports, a Djinn is not considered to be a visiting role. Similarly, although the primary visit of a Succubus is "visiting", the secondary visit (i.e. selecting the destination of the redirect) is not.

Would either of these cases trigger a player to be killed if selecting the same target as an Omegawolf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these scenarios would result in the Coven player ending up as Omegadogfood.

The Succubus would only be in danger of dying if their first target was the scene of the Omegawolf's massacre.

In addition, if the Succubus successfully redirects a player to the Omegawolf's target, then the redirected player would be killed.